# Linkify onLongClick only

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, linkify

I implemented Linkify into my EditText view using this code http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/linkify.html but it is extremely difficult to edit the Links inside of a EditText since a single click opens up the link.

How can I change Linkify so that is only opens links with onLongClick() that way it is still simple to make changes to the Links.